# storing array of objects ang then check previous and next item

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-ui

I should be able to add input for user A and user B and when I click previous it will display the previous one and when I click next it will display the next inputs back and forth. Thanks for any help.

It will ask input for user A after that we click next and will ask for input for user b after that when I click back it should display input of the previous user and if I click next if will display the next user.

but when I keep navigating next and prev it no longer display the data. waht is the issue with this guys ?

```js
//event.js
const showModal = document.querySelector("#showModal");
const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
const nextBtn = document.querySelector("#next-btn");
const prevBtn = document.querySelector("#prev-btn");
let userText = document.querySelector(".user-text");

showModal.addEventListener("click", e => {
  modal.setAttribute("style", "display:block");
});

nextBtn.addEventListener("click", e => {
  userText.textContent = "User B";
  prevBtn.setAttribute("style", "display:inline-block");
});
prevBtn.addEventListener("click", e => {
  userText.textContent = "User A";
  prevBtn.setAttribute("style", "display:none");
});

//class.js
const mainForm = document.querySelector("#mainForm");
const fnameValue = document.querySelector("#fname");
const lnameValue = document.querySelector("#lname");
const idValue = document.querySelector("#idValue");

class User {
  constructor() {
    this.userArrHolder = [];
  }
  addUser(id, fname, lname) {
    const newAddedUser = {
      id: id,
      fname: fname,
      lname: lname,
    };

    if (this.userArrHolder.length > 0) {
      // displaying first user in ui
      this.userArrHolder.forEach(item => {
        idValue.value = item.id;
        fnameValue.value = item.fname;
        lnameValue.value = item.lname;
        console.log("display A");
      });

      // adding the second user
      this.userArrHolder.push(newAddedUser);
    } else {
      // add new user
      this.userArrHolder.push(newAddedUser);
      fnameValue.value = "";
      lnameValue.value = "";
    }
  }
  // looping thru array
  displayUser(id) {
    idValue.value = id;
    this.userArrHolder.forEach((item, index) => {
      idValue.value = item.id;
      fnameValue.value = item.fname;
      lnameValue.value = item.lname;
    });
  }
}

const newUser = new User();
mainForm.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  // validating if adding a user or display
  if (!idValue.value) {
    let id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
    newUser.addUser(id, fnameValue.value, lnameValue.value);
    console.log("add", newUser.userArrHolder);
  } else {
    newUser.displayUser(idValue.value);
    console.log("display", newUser.userArrHolder);
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="show-modal">
      <button id="showModal">Show Modal</button>
    </div>

    <div class="modal">
      <div class="modal-wrapper">
        <p class="user-text">User A</p>
        <form action="" id="mainForm">
          <label for="fname">First Name:</label><br />
          <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" /><br />
          <label for="lname">Last Name:</label><br />
          <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" />
          <div class="btn-container">
            <button
              type="submit"
              id="prev-btn"
              class="pr"
              style="display: none"
            >
              Prev
            </button>
            <button type="submit" id="next-btn">Next</button>
          </div>
          <input type="text" name="idValue" id="idValue" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Shouldn't your `<script>` tags be *inside* the body (right *before* the closing `</body>` rather than *after* it)?

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: In your HTML file, `<script src="event.js"></script>` and `<script src="class.js"></script>` are *after* the closing `</body>` tag; shouldn't they be *before* it?

Comment: nah it is working , the problem I am asking is on the logic

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Where are you storing this Array? What would happen when you go to Next pr Previous item? please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following Example (using jQuery UI for Dialog)

```js
$(function() {
  var Users = [];
  var pos = 0;

  function showPrev() {
    pos--;
    showUser(Users[pos]);
    if (pos == 0) {
      $("#show-users ~ div.ui-dialog-buttonpane div.ui-dialog-buttonset button:eq(0)").addClass("hidden");
    }
    if ($("#show-users ~ div.ui-dialog-buttonpane div.ui-dialog-buttonset button:eq(1)").hasClass("add-user")) {
      $("#show-users ~ div.ui-dialog-buttonpane div.ui-dialog-buttonset button:eq(1)").html("Next").removeClass("add-user ui-priority-primary");
    }
  }

  function showNext() {
    if ($("#show-users ~ div.ui-dialog-buttonpane div.ui-dialog-buttonset button:eq(1)").hasClass("add-user")) {
      addUser($("#fname").val(), $("#lname").val());
      showUser(Users[Users.length - 1]);
      pos = Users.length - 1;
      $("#show-users ~ div.ui-dialog-buttonpane div.ui-dialog-buttonset button:eq(1)").html("Next").removeClass("add-user ui-priority-primary");
    } else {
      pos++;
      if (pos == Users.length) {
        showUser({
          fname: "",
          lname: "",
          id: ""
        });
        $("#show-users ~ div.ui-dialog-buttonpane div.ui-dialog-buttonset button:eq(1)").html("Add").addClass("add-user ui-priority-primary");
      } else {
        showUser(Users[pos]);
      }
    }
    if (pos != 0) {
      $("#show-users ~ div.ui-dialog-buttonpane div.ui-dialog-buttonset button:eq(0)").removeClass("hidden");
    }
  }

  function newUser(fname, lname) {
    return {
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
      fname: fname,
      lname: lname
    };
  }

  function addUser(fname, lname) {
    Users.push(newUser(fname, lname));
  }

  function showUser(data, $target) {
    $target = ($target != undefined ? $target : $("#show-users"));
    $("#fname", $target).val(data.fname);
    $("#lname", $target).val(data.lname);
    $("#idValue", $target).val(data.id);
  }

  function makeTable(arr, $target) {
    $target = ($target != undefined ? $target : $("body"));
    var tbl = $("<table>", {
      class: "ui-widget ui-corner-all"
    }).css({
      width: "100%",
      borderCollapse: "collapse",
    });
    if ($target != false) {
      tbl.appendTo($target);
    }
    if (arr.length == 0) {
      return tbl;
    }
    var head = $("<thead>", {
      class: "ui-widget-header"
    }).appendTo(tbl);
    var body = $("<tbody>", {
      class: "ui-widget-content"
    }).appendTo(tbl);
    $("<tr>").appendTo(head);
    $("<th>").html("ID").appendTo($("tr", head));
    $("<th>").html("First Name").appendTo($("tr", head));
    $("<th>").html("Last Name").appendTo($("tr", head));
    $.each(arr, function(i, row) {
      $("<tr>").appendTo(body);
      $.each(row, function(k, v) {
        $("<td>", {
          class: "ui-widget-content"
        }).html(v).appendTo($("tr:last", body));
      });
    });
    $("tr", body).eq(pos).addClass("ui-priority-primary");
    return tbl;
  }

  addUser("John", "Smith");
  addUser("Jane", "Smith");
  showUser(Users[pos]);

  $("#show-users").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: [{
        text: "Prev",
        class: (pos != 0 ? "" : "hidden"),
        click: showPrev
      },
      {
        text: "Next",
        click: showNext
      },
      {
        text: "Cancel",
        click: function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    ]
  });

  $("#showModal").click(function() {
    $("#show-users").dialog("open");
  });

  $("#showAll").click(function() {
    var dlg = $("<div>", {
      title: "All Users"
    }).html(makeTable(Users, false));
    dlg.dialog({
      modal: true,
      autoOpen: true,
      close: function() {
        $(this).dialog("destroy");
        dlg.remove();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#mainForm label,
#mainform input {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonset button.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="show-modal">
  <button id="showModal">Show Modal</button>
</div>
<div class="show-all">
  <button id="showAll">Show All Users</button>
</div>

<div class="modal" title="Show Users" id="show-users">
  <form action="" id="mainForm">
    <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" />
    <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" />
    <input type="hidden" name="idValue" id="idValue" />
  </form>
</div>
```

If you choose to not use the jQuery UI Dialog window, the other functions and basic ideas still apply.

You will have an Array of Users and an Pointer or Index counter, this will be set to `0` or the specific Index of the array. These should be available so you can read or modify them as needed. You will then have various functions to update the UI and modify data depending on the Users interactions.

- Prev - Reduce the Pointer and show the Previous User data from the Array

  - Cannot drop below `0` index
  - Hide Prev button when Pointer is `0`
- Next - Increment the Pointer and show the Next User data from the Array

  - Cannot exceed last Index
  - Clear form for new User entry if on beyond the last Index
  - Show Prev button when Pointer is not `0`